# Redirection of a link

Tags: php, html, redirect, php-5.3

I have made a website for a college project, the link is http://beprjcom.000webhostapp.com/.

There a functionality that user can add a query that has to be monitored by the admin, but for this the user has to logged in. So, there's a link "Add Query" on the top right section of the website. So, if a user is not logged in and he clicks on the link, then the user should be redirected to the login page and this is working properly on my localhost environment. But, when I uploaded the files to the hosting server, and when I click on "Add Query", it simply gives me a blank page when not logged in.

Here's the code for the "Add Query" page.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['person'])){
    header("Location: ./signup.php");
    }else{

include('./head.php'); 
?>
<title> Home </title>
</head>
<body class="green lighten-2">

<?php include('./nav.php'); ?>

 <div class="parallax-container">
      <div class="parallax"><img src="img/cover.png"></div>
</div>
<!-- This Code is designed and developed by Ashish Chawla -->



<div class="container">
<h3 class="center-align"> Fill up this form</h3>
<h4 class="center-align">And we shall convey the same to authority in-charge</h4>
<div class="card-panel hoverable">
    <form class="col s12 l8" action="querypros.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['person']; ?>">

    <div class="file-field input-field">
      <div class="btn">
        <span>File</span>
        <input type="file" name="img">
      </div>
      <div class="file-path-wrapper">
        <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
    </div>
    </div>

     <div class="input-field col s12">
          <textarea id="textarea1" name="desc" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
          <label for="textarea1">Description of the Query</label>
        </div>

  <div id="locationField" class="input-field col s12">
      <input id="autocomplete" name="address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text">

    </div>
 <table id="address">
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" name="street" id="street_number" ></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <!-- Note: Selection of address components in this example is typical.
             You may need to adjust it for the locations relevant to your app. See
             https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
        -->
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" name="city" id="locality" ></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" name="state" id="administrative_area_level_1" ></input></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" name="zip" id="postal_code" ></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" name="country" id="country" ></input></td>
      </tr>
    </table>


      <script type="text/javascript">

      // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
      // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      var placeSearch, autocomplete;
      var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
      };

      function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
      }

      function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
          document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }

      </script>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC_vB5-cVliYDE9YLkd4l7eVjsr3Z15ymY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>


    <center><input type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" value="Submit"></center>
</form>
</div>
<br>
</div>



<?php include('./footer.php'); ?>

<?php } ?>
```

signup.php

```
<?php include('./head.php'); ?>
<title>Sign up</title>
</head>
<body class="green lighten-2">
<?php include ('./nav.php'); ?><br><br>

<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 l6">

    <div class="card-panel hoverable">

    <h3 class="center-align">Login</h3>

    <form action="login.php" method="post">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
         <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
          <input id="email1" name="email1" type="email" >
         <label for="email1" data-error="wrong" data-success="">Email</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">vpn_key</i>
            <input id="password1" name="password1" type="password" >
          <label for="password1">Password</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <center>
            <button class="btn green  waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Login
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
          </button>
    </center>

    <a href="./reset.php"> Forgot Password? </a>

     </form>
     </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<!-- Form Validation Scripts -->
<script>

$(document).ready(function (){

    $('#myForm').validate({

        rules: {
            phone: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            phone: "Enter a valid phone number"
        }
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
         }
    });

});

</script>
    <div class="col s12 l6">

    <div class="card-panel hoverable">

    <h3 class="center-align">Sign Up</h3>

<div class="innerdiv">

    <form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="reg.php" method="POST">

     <div class="row">  
        <div class="input-field col s12">
         <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
          <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required>
          <label for="name">Name</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
         <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
          <input id="email" name="email" type="email" required>
           <label for="email" data-error="wrong" data-success="">Email</label>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">


        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
            <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" data-length="10" required>
          <label for="phone" data-error="incorrect" data-success="">Phone Number</label>
        </div>

         <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">vpn_key</i>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" required>
          <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>
    </div>



    <center>
            <button class="btn green  waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Sign Up
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
          </button>
    </center>

     </form>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>

<?php include('./footer.php'); ?>
```

Kindly help.

Comment: You should avoid working with PHP 5.3 right now. It is a vulnerable version whose end-of-life was reached long ago. Try updating to PHP 5.6 or even better to the new PHP 7.x branches.

Comment: Why not hide the button to addquery page on homepage when you are not logged in?

Comment: Is your LIVE Server running PHP 5.3? I would certainly hope not?

Comment: @versvs I tried running on PHP 5.6, still the same issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, its on 5.3..

Comment: _“it simply gives me a blank page when not logged in”_ - then configure PHP to properly show errors first of all, see duplicate for details.

Comment: @CBroe what's duplicate here?

Comment: The duplicate explains how to _debug_ cases of _“it simply gives me a blank page”_ ...